# jquery search on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a button like this

```
<input type='button' id='button' value='search'/>
```

i have this url

```
url = "localhost/mywebsite/mypage.html
```

i want when a user press the button, a jquery function fire to search that url for a specfic data, i tried like this;

```
$("#button).on('click'function(){
$(get).(url).search('data');
});
```

but i didnt get any resutls , why please?
How to Tag

Comment: because it's wrong. Where did you find the `.search()` method and read to use `.get()` like that? Please post a link to the Docs

Comment: `$(get).(url).search('data');` this line does not do anything

Comment: @roXon my friend told me about it, i haven't read about it before

Comment: @ashley what is the another solution pelase?

Comment: I would read the jQuery documentation first (AJAX (GET,POST,LOAD)) and than try my self, and than ask a question. You're even missing `"` and `,` all over the place. Please show some effort next time! :)

Comment: you need to read the docs to get what you want. http://api.jquery.com/ . looks like you will need the `.load` function

Comment: could you help me please if you know the answer ?

Comment: please help help help, i need help

Answer (score 1):

You need the following jQuery:

```
$("#button").on('click', function () {
    $('#get').load(url);
});
```

---

Where, `#get` is

```
<div id='get'>
</div>
```

Comment: and how to search please?

Answer (score 1):

Just and example would be:

```
var url = "localhost/mywebsite/mypage.html";
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    $('body').load( url +" #content" );
});
```

will load `#content` from your other page into `body`

Comment: so if i need to load an <a> tag, i will write `.load(url+"a")` right?